# How to retrieve excel files through user input?

Tags: python, pandas

I hope that I am able to manually access my local files to retrieve my files(csv/xlsx) and put it in a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

df = pd.read_excel("(Nov 2017) Case Download Export.xlsx")

df["Problem Description"]
df["Lowercase"] = df["Problem Description"].apply(lambda x: " " .join(word.lower() for word in str(x).split()))

df.to_csv("Oct17.csv", index = None, header=True)
```

The code that I did is manually entered the file name and load. 
I hope to browse and select the files myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
mypath = "C:\\..."   #folder with all your file
files_name= [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

file name give you a list with the name of all the file in the folder

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, you are still stating the path to look through. I hope that I can browse own my own and select the files.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if this is possible :/